# Не могу разобраться с вложенными циклами в js

Tags: javascript, html

С помощью двух вложенных циклов выведите на экран следующую строку:

```
11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33
```

Я не соображу НИКАК, как эту "штуку" сделать.

```js
let result77 = '';

for (let i = 10; i <= 12; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
    result77 = i + j + ' ';
    document.write(result77);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// первый цикл - первая цифра
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  // второй цикл - вторая цифра
  for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
    // записываем конкатенацию (вместо сложения) чисел с добавлением пробела
    document.write('' + i + j + ' ');
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Научил, как смотреть на такие вопросы. Помог))

Answer (score 0):

Еще один подход: первый цикл - шаг в 10, второй - шаг в 1.

```
for (let i = 10; i <= 30; i += 10) {
    let num;
    for (let j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
        num = i + j;
        document.write(num + ' ');
    }
}
```